# C# Button.PerformClick() not triggering

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button/labels/contextmenustrip. Code running well except after running Application.Restart().

```
private void ContextMenuStrip_Home_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripItem Structure = e.ClickedItem;

    switch (Structure.Text)
    {
        case "Dog":
            Application.Restart();
            Button_Dog.PerformClick();
            break;
        case "Cat":
            Application.Restart();
            Button_Cat.PerformClick();
            break;
        case "Bird":
            Application.Restart();
            Button_Bird.PerformClick();
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Not Assigned Yet");
            break;
    }
}
```

All of the buttons are clickable in winforms, but I need to programatically click it after restarting the application via application.restart. What else am I missing? Or it will not trigger after all? After showing of a new instance.

Comment: [The most common reason for calling Restart is to start a new version of the application that you have downloaded through ClickOnce using the Update or UpdateAsync method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These buttons don't exist in the application after you restart the application.  There are new buttons with the same identifiers and labels inside the new instance of the application, but the references you have don't point to them.

Comment: what should be a possible remedy with this problem?

Comment: The design seems fundamentally flawed.  Why do you want to restart the application whenever anyone clicks anything?  You should be able to find the control that you're interested in by searching through [`Application.OpenForms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) after restart, but this is probably still wrong even if it accomplishes that goal.

Comment: because i have list of items in contextmenustrip which are selectable items.these items are related to the animal buttons. For example, www.ebay.com, if you select an item inside "My ebay", the current lay-out/view of the page will hide and it will open new instances/page, so an item inside "My ebay" is related to something button.performclick(). Wherever you are in ebay page, but when you click an item in contextmenustrip it will show new instances. every item has their own control to show.

Comment: @HardDisk - Create a new form instance and call the `Show()` method.  Don't restart the application.

Comment: i created new form instance and call the show and hide the current form but how to show the layout after performing button.performclick().?